# cannot solve this factorial problem getting error on for loop

Tags: javascript, html

I saw other logic that work properly but what is the problem in my logic! I am trying to solve it with my logic but can't detect the problem. I am coding in javascript. Is there something I missing!

Here is the code:

```js
var number = 10;
var up = document.getElementById('GFG_UP');
var down = document.getElementById('GFG_DOWN');


up.innerHTML = "Click on the button to calculate"
  + " the factorial of n.<br>n = " + number;

function Factorial(number) {

  for (let i = 1; i < number; i++) {
    number *= (number - i);
  }
  return number;
}

function GFG_Fun() {
  down.innerHTML = Factorial(number);
}
```

```html
<h1 style="color:green;">
  GeeksForGeeks
</h1>

<p id="GFG_UP" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;"></p>

<button onclick="GFG_Fun()">
  Click Here
</button>

<p id="GFG_DOWN" style="color:green; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function Factorial(number) {
 let out = 1
 for (let i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
  out *= i;
 }
 return out;
} 

console.log(Factorial(0))
console.log(Factorial(5))
```

OR

```
function Factorial(n) {
    let out = 1
    while (n) {
        out *= (n--)
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I prefer the first answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to use one more variable to hold the final value of factorial, In your code you're manipulating the same `number` variable which you used as a counter as well.

```
  number *= (number-1)
```

---

```html
<head>
  <title>
    Factorial of a number using JavaScript
  </title>
</head>

<body style="text-align:center;">

  <h1 style="color:green;">
    GeeksForGeeks
  </h1>

  <p id="GFG_UP" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">
  </p>

  <button onclick="GFG_Fun()"> 
        Click Here 
    </button>

  <p id="GFG_DOWN" style="color:green; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
  </p>

  <script>
    var number = 10;
    var up = document.getElementById('GFG_UP');
    var down = document.getElementById('GFG_DOWN');


    up.innerHTML = "Click on the button to calculate" +
      " the factorial of n.<br>n = " + number;

    function Factorial(number) {
      let final = number === 0 ? 1 : number
      for (let i = 1; i < number; i++) {
        final *= i;
      }
      return final;
    }

    function GFG_Fun() {
      down.innerHTML = Factorial(number);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you . You give me the exact  solution what I was needed. I am facing another problem which I have already posted . Can you help me about that?